# Parameter Count Mismatch when loading exe entrypoint C#

Tags: c#

I have a .net exe in a byte array. I load it as assembly and try to invoke it's entry point

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(buff);
var entryPoint = assembly.EntryPoint;
var commandArgs = new string[0];
var returnValue = entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { commandArgs });
```

with my test exe witch is some silly command line app that outputs "hello", it works. With some other third party exe however it fails with `Parameter Count Mismatch`

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.a() in C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\OLD\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\Program.cs:line 211
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\OLD\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\Program.cs:line 41
```

Why?

Here is what I know for that exe - it is .net, it has public static void main() method and it is correctly identified as the entry point and it is relatively small and simple app in a single exe.

Comment: Could you show your invoked `Main` method.

Comment: what do you mean? it is an entrypoint object with underlying MethodInfo object. Dissasembled with ILSpy it looks like this : using System;

namespace j
{
 public class A
 {
  [STAThread]
  public static void main()
  {
   OK.ko();
  }
 }
}

Comment: `public static void main()` suggests that you don't need your `commandArgs` argument, since `main` method doesn't take any arguments. Try `entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[0]);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you can declare entry point either with single parameter of type string[] (such as *static void Main(string[] args)*) or with no paramaters (such as *static void Main()*). Exe file you are trying to run probably uses the latter method, so you can't pass any commandline arguments to it - at least that's what error message tells you - wrong number of parameters.

So to run it, you would have to call it without arguments:

```
var returnValue = entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```